# Angular 9 : How to load spa before load an extarnal script js

Tags: javascript, angular, single-page-application

I have an external javascript js in my SPA. When I rum my SPA this last will be loaded after the load of the js script. I want that the page will be loaded before the execute of the script because if the server of the script down the spa will not be displayed.

**I can't use async or defer**

Answer (score 2):

Try dynamically injecting script tags from JS code of your SPA. In that way, we can remove the External JS file from initial loading, and loading it whenever it's required.

[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts)

Example:

```
function loadError(){
 console.error('Script Loading Failed');}

function loadSuccess(){
console.info('Script Loaded Successfully');}

var scriptElementment = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript'; 
scriptElement.defer=true;
scriptElement.onload= loadSuccess; //Function to be invoked , when script is loaded successfully
scriptElement.onerror=loadError; //Function to be invoked, when any error occurred during script loading 
document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
scriptElement.src= 'https://example.com/sample.js'; //URL of file
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It'd be great if you could provide an example, or a link to documentation explaining your solution.

Comment: Updated the answer with an example. Thanks @Matt